# Automatically selects other row of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to develop a billing system swing application,but i stuck at a place.I want after bill the JTable row selection **moves to first row** for next billing, but after submission the last or other row selection occur.Please help me...
[After KeyPressed Event]
The key binding is as follows..

```
InputMap im = cartTable.getInputMap();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "Action.NextCell");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0), "Action.NextCell");

ActionMap am = cartTable.getActionMap();
am.put("Action.NextCell", new AbstractAction(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int col = cartTable.getSelectedColumn();
        int row = cartTable.getSelectedRow();

        if(col==0 && cartTable.getValueAt(row, col)==null){
            ProductListForm productList=new ProductListForm();
            productList.setVisible(true);
        }else if(col==1 && ProductListForm.product.getName()!=null){
            setValueToTable();
        }else if(col==7){
            calculateValue();
        }else if(col==9){
            calculateTotal();
            row++;
            col=-1;
        }
        col++;
        cartTable.changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
        cartTable.editCellAt(row, col);
    }
});
```

The bill submission code is this..

```
if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Saved", "message", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            savePurchaseDetails();
            saveStockDetails();
            resetPage();
            updateReturnTable();
            int result=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you want to print reciept?", "Print Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(result==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){

            }
            cartTable.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        }
```

Comment: Plese provide a [mcve] so we can also run it, see your problem and provide a solution. Please don't copy/paste your whole code, just create a small piece of it, which is still compilable, runnable and demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I really am not sure what you are asking but you are using Key Bindings incorrectly. You should NOT be using a KeyListener to add a Key Binding. When you use Key Bindings, you add the binding when you create the table, not when the Enter key is pressed. A JTable already has a default Action for the Enter key. So you will want to "replace" the default Action with a custom Action of your own. The easiest way to change the selected row of a table is to just use the `changeSelection()` method of the table.

Comment: You can check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the list of current bindings on a JTable as well as examples of how to change the bindings.

Comment: Now I used Key Bindings but problem remain same.the selection moves on the last row whereas I used changes election for 1st row.